# Email Alert on status field selection. Flow Trigger to compare last modified date

Tags: workflow, custom-object, lookup, contact

I have a requirement to send email alert when seminar attendee(custom object) is selected as contact (look up object) and seminar status as "attended". But when same contact is selected for another seminar attendee and status as "attended", email should not be sent . Only after 30 days if new seminar attendee is selected for this contact , then new email alert should trigger. 
I was able to set up process builder for this seminar attendee object and send email alert but need logic for 30 day calculation before another new email can trigger.

I tried to set up a formula field "Email Sent" on contact object to check true when first email is sent out and calculate 30 days.

Flow trigger to compare last modified date of  seminar attendee under contact to be more than 30 days from previous seminar attended under same contact before a new email is send out.

Can someone please with flow triggers. I am completely new to flows

Comment: Hi Joli -- welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Specifically, you'll need to show some effort use [edit] on what you've done to solve the problem

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion . i did mention that i created process builder for email alert and use formula field and status field to trigger that email. It's not working, no action.

Comment: have you tried process builder scheduled actions for this purpose?

Comment: Yes but scheduled actions trigger email only after mentioned duration during every new seminar attended where status is "attended" , while for my requirement i want email sent out the first time and from there till 30 days of other seminars attended no emails to be sent .

Comment: it is not clear why can't you use scheduled actions . If you need just one usual action (sent out email on the first time ) and also one scheduled action (send email in 30 days) then you could just combine these two actions in one flow. If this doesn't solve your problem, try to reformulate your question to explain why scheduled actions do not help to solve your case

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this by doing the following:

1. Create a custom checkbox field (**Email Sent in Last 30 Days**) on Contact object.
2. In Process Builder criteria for your Email Action, check for AND(Attendee__c.Contact__r.**Email Sent in Last 30 Days** = FALSE, TEXT(**Seminar Status**) = "Attended").
3. If criteria is met, send email and set Attendee__c.Contact__r.**Email Sent in Last 30 Days** to TRUE. This TRUE value will prevent this Contact from being emailed again (by the same action) via the **Email Sent in Last 30 Days** check in Step 2.
4. As a second action of the same criteria node, create a Scheduled Action which sets Attendee__c.Contact__r.**Email Sent in Last 30 Days** to FALSE 30 days after the trigger date. In 30 days a time-based action will set the Contact's **Email Sent in Last 30 Days** field to FALSE, re-enabling that Contact to receive another email alert.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes i havent thought out this possibility, yes let me give a try and check. Thank you for this .